# How does this C iteration work?

Tags: c, arrays, iteration

Sorry if this seems like a stupid question, but I came across this code that transforms a mixed-case string to a lower-case one, I understand it except the string iteration:

```
for (int i=0; str[i]; i++) {

    str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
}
```

In my understanding the expression `str[i]` means continue iterating *if* `str[i]` exists, is that correct? And does C not check the boundaries of an array which means that the loop code go on forever?

Comment: `for` loops do what the always do. no exception here.

Comment: The end-condition is equivalent to `str[i] != 0`, not "if `str[i]` exists".   By convention, a string in C is a sequence of `char`, terminated with a  `char` that has value `0`.    For example, `"AB"` is an array of three characters with values `'A'`, `'B'`, and `'\0'`.   The code will give undefined behaviour if `str` does not correspond to such a string (e.g. if it is an array without a terminating zero).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition `str[i]` tests for the end of the string. C-strings are null-terminated, so when the character `'\0'` is reached, the loop terminates.

No, C does not check array bounds.

Answer (score 2):

Having the guard as `str[i]` is the same as `str[i] != '\0'`, whereby the `'\0'` is the null-terminating character of a string. The guard of for loops either evaluates to true or false, or **0** and **1** in this case. Simply using `str[i]` checks if the character is valid(**true**), and not a null-terminating character(**false**), which marks the end of a string.

If your new to C strings, you can also just use `strlen()` from `<string.h>` for your guard. This function just returns the length of the string. Your code would then look like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < strlen(str); i++) {

    str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
}
```

Although this is valid, using the first approach is much easier to use and more C like.

Answer (score 0):

It will not go forever because every string (`char*`) has to end with `'\0'`. So it loops until `str[i]` is not `0`.

Answer (score 0):

In C every C-string ie. constant you would type is represented as for example:

```
string a = {'x', 'y', 'z', 0}
```

for

```
a = "xyz"
```

Therefore, the loop terminates when meets the last character since the last element is NULL (0) which is obviously false.

Answer (score -2):

You are right about the expression meaning "if(str[i])" exists, then continue iterating. However, the loop will NOT go on forever because once the value of "i" becomes greater than or equal to (>=) length of the array "str[]", the condition "if(str[i])" will fail. Thus, the loop will only execute as many times as the number of elements in the "str[]" array.